# Converting features to dummies

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, spread

I have this matrix:

```
quimio = matrix(c(51,33,16,58,29,13,48,42,30,26,38,16), 
            nrow = 4, ncol = 3)

colnames(quimio) = c("Pouca", "Média", "Alta")
rownames(quimio) = c("Tipo I", "Tipo II", "Tipo III", "Tipo IV")
```

Which looks like this:

```
          Pouca Média Alta
Tipo I      51    29   30
Tipo II     33    13   26
Tipo III    16    48   38
Tipo IV     58    42   16
```

I want to turn it into a tibble such that these row and column names are all dummy variables.

I wanted to make a bar chart and got this:

```
library(tidyverse)

tipo = c("Tipo I", "Tipo II", "Tipo III", "Tipo IV")

tipos = rep(tipo, 3)

quimiotb = as.tibble(quimio)
quimiotb = gather(quimiotb)
quimiotb$tipo = tipos

quimiotb = rename(quimiotb, reacao = key)
quimiotb$reacao = factor(quimiotb$reacao)
quimiotb$tipo = factor(quimiotb$tipo)
```

This is what I get:

```
A tibble: 12 x 3
reacao value tipo    
<fct>  <dbl> <fct>   
1 Pouca     51 Tipo I  
2 Pouca     33 Tipo II 
3 Pouca     16 Tipo III
4 Pouca     58 Tipo IV 
5 Média     29 Tipo I  
6 Média     13 Tipo II 
7 Média     48 Tipo III
8 Média     42 Tipo IV 
9 Alta      30 Tipo I  
10 Alta     26 Tipo II 
11 Alta     38 Tipo III
12 Alta     16 Tipo IV
```

And while this is quite ok to use for a bar chart with `ggplot2` I can't run any model on it - that would require that `tipo` got spread into 4 columns and `reacao` in 3. Right now this tibble's first line reads like "51 patients with Tipo I cancer had *pouca* reacao". I've thought about using `spread()` but can't find the proper combination of arguments. Any help would be appreciated.

tl;dr

I need to tidy `quimiotb` and don't know how

EDIT: Expected output should be something like this

```
  A tibble: Y x 7
  Pouca Media Alta Tipo I Tipo II Tipo III Tipo IV    
  <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct>  <fct>   <fct>     <fct>
1   0     1    0      0      1       0         0
2   1     0    0      1      0       0         0
```

Comment: Please also add at least a small part of your expected output.

Comment: R seldom, if ever, needs explicit transformation of factors to dummies, the modeling functions take care of that in a much more tested and safe way.

Comment: I just want to run an ANOVA to assess if ``tipo`` is related to ``reacao``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modelling routines will create a model.matrix for you internally without you having to specify it so this should be sufficient.

```
as.data.frame.table(quimio)
```

`model.matrix` can create a model matrix from that but you don't need it as seen in the code below.

Now you do things like:

```
DF <- as.data.frame.table(quimio)
fm0 <- lm(Freq ~ Var1, DF) # or maybe you want Var2?
fm1 <- lm(Freq ~ Var1 + Var2, DF) 
anova(fm0, fm1) # compare
```

or look at the t tests of the coefficients of `Var2` in the output of `summary(fm1)` to see if they are significantly different from zero.

Or maybe you want to do a chi squared test on the original data

```
chisq.test(quimio)
```

Anyways there are many modelling functions in R and you now have the data in the form you need and can explore them.

Comment: But how do I specify a formula for a model then?

Comment: Let's say I want to run an ANOVA, to see if cancer type is related to ``reacao``. How to specify the model's formula?

Comment: Have transferred my comments to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Less elegant than I wanted, but should work with `data.table` and `mltools`:

```
> df
    Tipo I Tipo II Tipo III Tipo IV Alta Média Pouca value
 1:      1       0        0       0    0     0     1    51
 2:      0       1        0       0    0     0     1    33
 3:      0       0        1       0    0     0     1    16
 4:      0       0        0       1    0     0     1    58
 5:      1       0        0       0    0     1     0    29
 6:      0       1        0       0    0     1     0    13
 7:      0       0        1       0    0     1     0    48
 8:      0       0        0       1    0     1     0    42
 9:      1       0        0       0    1     0     0    30
10:      0       1        0       0    1     0     0    26
11:      0       0        1       0    1     0     0    38
12:      0       0        0       1    1     0     0    16
```

#### Code

```
library(data.table)
library(mltools)

df <- quimio %>% 
    as.data.frame() %>%
    rownames_to_column() %>%
    gather(key, value, -rowname) %>%
    mutate(rowname = as.factor(rowname),
           key = as.factor(key)) %>%
    as.data.table() %>%
    one_hot() %>% 
    rename_all(.funs = funs(sub("^.+_", "", names(df))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be

```
fun <- function(x, y) setNames(tibble(a = 1, b = 1)[rep(1, quimio[x, y]), ], c(rownames(quimio)[x], colnames(quimio)[y]))
1 * !is.na(map2_dfr(row(quimio), col(quimio), fun))
#      Tipo I Pouca Tipo II Tipo III Tipo IV Média Alta
# [1,]      1     1       0        0       0     0    0
# [2,]      1     1       0        0       0     0    0
# [3,]      1     1       0        0       0     0    0
# ...
```

Here `fun` creates a tibble with two columns for a certain pair of rows and columns of `quimio`, where the number of rows is given as an entry in `quimio`. The second line goes over all column and row pairs, creates a tibble for each, binds them, and sets to zero all the remaining `NA` entries.